# The question is for eclipse javaEE version. The project was not built since its build path is incomplete

Tags: java, eclipse, path

The question is for eclipse `JavaEE` version. The project was not built since its build path is incomplete.

> Cannot find the classpath for java.io.IOException.

Fix the build path then try building this project "Project name". I tried everything on the internet but didn't work out. I checked my JDK bin path with environment variable but it is the same.

I upgraded my JDK last month but later installed the `eclipse` and tried to run the project. Don't know whats the problem is a great help if someone can help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check if you are using correct Java Compiler:

- Projects => Properties  => Java Compiler => Select right Java compiler

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, appreciate it bro, i will tag you in future my java questions when posting......!!! Thanks once again.

Comment: You are welcome. Pls accept this answer if it solve your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

High possibility is JRE System Library is not configured properly in "Java Build Path" of project in Eclipse.

Try these steps:

1. Go to Project => Properties => Java Build Path => Libraries tab
2. Remove current "JRE System Library"
3. "Add Library" button => "JRE System Library" => Select your new upgraded JDK
4. "Apply and Close" button
5. Go to Project => Clean => clean project.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it didn't worked. same error is present yet. Do you have any other solution for this. Thanks!